# How do I assert array includes object that contains specific values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chai

Let's say I send GET request and response is array with 30 objects.

Now I want to check that it contains one object with specific values, I don't care about every single value inside that object.

I have tried the following assertions but they always fail due other objects not matching, I only care about one instance of this data so what should my assertion be?

I get errors like this:

```
AssertionError: expected an element of [ { description: null, …(7) }, …(28) ] to be like { …(2) }
```

Using Chai:

```
.expect((ctx) => {
        chai.expect(ctx.res.body.result).to.be.an('array').that.contains.something.like(
            {
                name: "7-Day Standard Trial",
                prices: [
                    {
                        currency: "usd",
                        interval: "day",
                        interval_count: "7",
                        is_recurring: false,
                        is_trial: true,
                        price_usd: "9.0"
                    },
                ]
            }
        )
```

Using PactumJS:

```
.expectJsonLike(
        { 
            result: [
                {
                    name: "7-Day Standard Trial",
                    prices: [
                        {
                            currency: "usd",
                            interval: "day",
                            interval_count: "7",
                            is_recurring: false,
                            is_trial: true,
                            price_usd: "9.0"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
      )
```

Comment: I'm sure you could just write your own test and assert that the test is true with Chai. By "own test" I mean write it how you would without Chai, then you can use Chai's assert to assert that your own test works.

Comment: I have written a test and tried to asserting using Chai...

Comment: Yeah but you are using Chai's chainable API, not something like `ctx.res.body.result.some((object) => ...)`. I don't think Chai can do what you want.

Comment: I'm using Chai what it is intended for? If I follow your suggestion I'm not even checking if the response array exists.

Comment: Why not start with `ctx.res.body.result.find(...)` then assert on the resulting object?